# Rendering MySQL result in Express/Node.js: Cannot assign to read only property '_locals'

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm trying to use Handlebars to display some data returned from a MySQL query. The route looks like the following:

```
var query = "SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table WHERE section >= " + start + " AND section <= " + end + " ORDER BY col1 ASC";

connection.query(query, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err

    var data = JSON.stringify(result);

    console.log(data);

    res.render('text', data);
});
```

'data' looks exactly how I want it, with an array of objects that have the three columns and the correct values. The relevant section of my handlebars looks like:

```
{{#each data}}{{data.col2}}{{/each}}
```

And then when I try to load the page, I get the following error (I can show more if it would help):

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_locals' of <and then my array of objects followed by a stack trace>
```

I think I'm not understanding something about how the MySQL query is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `JSON.stringify()` line completely and pass `{ result: result }` (or just `{ result }` if you have a modern version of node (v4.x+)) directly to your `res.render()`.

That line is actually converting the database result to a JSON *string*. A JSON *string* and a JavaScript object are not the same. By leaving off the `JSON.stringify()`, you are keeping `result` a proper array (not a string containing an array) which can be iterated in your template.

Also, your handlebars template would need to look like:

```
{{#each result}}{{this.col2}}{{/each}}
```

Comment: Ok, so my result is now a nameless array of RowDataPacket as so:

`[ RowDataPacket { col1: 1, col2: 'Lorem', col3: ' ' },
  RowDataPacket { col1: 2, col2: 'ipsum', col3: '' },
  RowDataPacket { col1: 3, col2: 'dolor', col3: ' ' },
  RowDataPacket { col1: 4, col2: 'sit'', col3: ', ' }`

If I pass this to handlebars as "result", how do I loop over it? {{each result}}{{result.col2}}{{/each}} isn't working.

Comment: @mscdex : Put query result in { } saved my day. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are passing string type `data` to the template.

Try replacing the line

`res.render('text', data);`

to

`res.render('text', result);`

Comment: @Kramhsiri change to `res.render('text', {result: result});` then your loop will work.